# Inserting multipe rows from dynamic form fields using laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I store multiple form array data in laravel, as I need to create a new record against each array index.

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [make] => test
            [model] => XYZ
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [make] => s4
            [model] => BB
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [make] => 99
            [model] => AX
        )
```

This is what I am trying to, but here loop get executed 6 times instead of three

```
$results = $request->all();
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
            echo $key;
            // insert operation

        }
```

Comment: share your form code also ?

Comment: i am using vue.js where form fields are dynamically added.https://jsfiddle.net/dmf2crzL/8/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should specify the control/field because the Request contains other (non-data) information. Something like:

```
$results = $request['array_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#inserts

```
Model::insert($request->all())
```

This will mass insert each array into your database. insert do not automatically set datetime values for created_at and updated_at, note that the array keys should match your table columns, and make sure your model has these fields as $fillables.